# ComputeThinU VS ComputeFullU in Eigen JacobiSVD

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I'm trying to solve a linear equation using JacobiSVD in Eigen. There are two decomposition options for JacobiSVD: ComputeThinU and ComputeFullU. Their meanings are explained as

- ComputeFullU: in JacobiSVD to indicate that the square matrix U is to be computed.
- ComputeThinU：in JacobiSVD to indicate that the thin matrix U is to be computed.

What does the "thin matrix" mean? And how do I determine which option to use?

Answer (score 2):

if you look at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html then in **Detailed Description** one can find this

> You can ask for only thin U or V to be computed, meaning the following. In case of a rectangular n-by-p matrix, letting m be the smaller value among n and p, there are only m singular vectors; the remaining columns of U and V do not correspond to actual singular vectors. Asking for thin U or V means asking for only their m first columns to be formed. So U is then a n-by-m matrix, and V is then a p-by-m matrix. Notice that thin U and V are all you need for (least squares) solving.

When to use what? If you need the U and V in its full glory, take "Full", if you need only the first `m` columns to do least squares, then take "Thin". Regards, M.